# Visual Studio 2017: No Intellisense from cordova-bluetoothle-plugin

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2017, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

These are my first step with cordova and I want to create an (Android) Cordova App with Bluetooth Support. So I created a blank Cordova App in VS2017 and added some buttons, the preview is working fine on my Nexus 7 Tablet.

Then I imported the [cordova-bluetoothle-plugin](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) over the UI that VS2017 supports when opening the config.xml file. One would expect Intellisense is available when typing `bluetoothle` but there is none.

I found an [Known Issue](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/known-issues-general/#strongmissing-intellisensestrong) on the Visual Studio Website but it's no longer maintained, so I am not sure if it's still applicable.

Adding `"/// <reference group="Implicit (Multi-Device Apps)" />"`at the beginning of the `bluetoothle.js` located in the Project Folder `plugins\cordova-plugin-bluetoothle\www` didn't work.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

**Versions in use:**

Visual Studio 15.3.5
Cordova 6.3.1
cordova-plugin-bluteoothle 4.4.2

Find the content of the config.xml below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myappab3af9" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="de-DE">
      <name>BlankCordovaApp1</name>
      <description>Ein leeres Projekt, das Apache Cordova verwendet, damit Sie eine App für mehrere mobile Plattformen erstellen können: Android, iOS und die universelle Windows-Plattform.</description>
      <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Ihr Name hier</author>
      <vs:template-name>BlankJS</vs:template-name>
      <vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
      <engine name="android" spec="5.2.1" />
      <engine name="ios" spec="4.2.0" />
      <engine name="windows" spec="4.4.2" />
      <content src="index.html" />
      <access origin="*" />
      <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
      <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
      <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
      <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
      <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
      <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
      <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="android">
        <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="ios">
        <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="windows">
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" height="44" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" height="71" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
        <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="android">
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="windows">
        <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
        <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
        <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
      </platform>
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-bluetoothle" spec="~4.4.2" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
      <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="25" />
      <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="~1.2.4" />
    </widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the right way, but adding

`/// <reference path="..\..\plugins\cordova-plugin-bluetoothle\types\index.d.ts" />`

at the top of the index.js file seems to work. Using the 'reference group' directive lead to a syntax error.